# Linking by ID in react in same page

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to make a 1 page website in react and I have divided it into multiple components. So, I have a navbar component and an education component. Now I want to link navbar to education.
In App.js I am doing this

```
        <Education id="edu"></Education>
```

and in navbar I am linking like this

`<NavLink href="#edu" className="navlink">
              Education
            </NavLink>`

But it is not working.

Comment: Do you mean routing/navigation between pages or jumping to sections on the same page?

Comment: I meant jumping to sections of the same page. But the problem is that I have defined buttons in the Navbar component and I want to jump to Another component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React itself only handles the presentational responsibilities and won't handle navigation or routing. A popular choice of library for handling navigation between page components in React is [ReactRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).

When using React Router you would have your root component wrapper in a `Router` component. You would then link components together using a `Link` component. [See this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).

Note that this is the most popular way of handling routing navigation with React single page web applications but it is not the only way.